# Visual foxpro table name with variable

Tags: foxpro, dbf

I have to modify an old software wrote in visual foxpro (latest version) 
My goal is to create some temporary tables with a non-fixed name (it depends on some variable). 
How can I write something like: 
variable1="table_name"
Create table variable1 (field1 int, field2 int)

and have the output file table_name.dbf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a small change to what you wrote will do the trick:

```
variable1 = "table_name"
CREATE TABLE (variable1) (field1 int, field2 int)
```